# flutter build_runner giving 0 output after being executed

Tags: json, flutter, serialization, build-runner

Im having issues to get the desired output for my json file with the build_runner it runs successfully but isn't giving any outputs

**my first.dart file**

````
```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'first.g.dart';


@JsonSerializable()
class User {
String visibility, name;
User(this.visibility, this.name);

 factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);


 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```
````

Do my project need any buil.yaml file in my project?

**my pubspec.yaml file**

````
```
dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter
 json_annotation: ^4.4.0
 http: ^0.13.4

dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
 build_runner: ^2.1.7
 json_serializable: ^6.1.1
 ```
````

This is what my terminal looks like after execution of command

```
 flutter pub run build_runner build
```

**terminal**

```
 PS D:\Flutter\json_parse\learn> flutter pub run build_runner build
 [INFO] Generating build script...
 [INFO] Generating build script completed, took 359ms

 [INFO] Precompiling build script......
 [INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 7.0s

 [INFO] Initializing inputs
 [INFO] Building new asset graph...
 [INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 758ms

 [INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
 [INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms

 [INFO] Running build...
 [INFO] Generating SDK summary...
 [INFO] 3.5s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
 [INFO] Generating SDK summary completed, took 3.5s

 [INFO] 4.6s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
 [INFO] 5.6s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
 [INFO] 7.0s elapsed, 0/3 actions completed.
 [INFO] 12.9s elapsed, 1/3 actions completed.
 [INFO] Running build completed, took 13.6s

 [INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
 [INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 30ms

 [INFO] Succeeded after 13.6s with 0 outputs (6 actions)
```

I'm not getting what is the problem in my code

Comment: how you are looking at the output? Did you write any code for...It`s running with the success though...

Comment: I am getting the json file through api and want to convert the json format to dart format so i can use the data in my application, I watched videos on YouTube about json serialization and tried to implement it but im not able to get output. There is no error and nor any json data output just the command runs successfully.

Comment: you can refer here: [demo implemenation](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/automatic-generate-json-serializable-in-flutter-4c9d2d23ed88) .

Comment: Nothing changed still getting the same issue. Should I have a build.yaml file ?

Comment: I think it is present on ```pubspec.yaml``` file.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this issue before. I observed that the build_runner output gave us 0 if the code was not saved before running build_runner. I therefore recommend that,

> ***"Before running build runner, consider saving your changes of the data class."***

Answer (score 2):

Solved by

```
flutter clean
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in pubspec.ymal file

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hive: ^2.2.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.10
  json_annotation: ^3.0.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.0.0
  hive_generator: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.3.1
  json_serializable: ^3.2.2
```

Comment: As your snippet is YAML, please use code-block formatting to make its indentation clear. (I'd edit it for you, but I wouldn't trust myself to guess the proper indentation, which is critical for YAML.)

Answer (score 0):

Add **"hive_generator: ^2.0.0"** and **"build_runner: ^2.3.2"** to the **"dev_dependencies:"** section of the "pubspec.yaml" file.

And then use this command in the terminal:
**flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --use-polling-watcher --delete-conflicting-outputs**

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting to check your pubspec.yaml spaces. I checked and found some are off set. It works after correcting them back in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your syntax for part is correct.

for json_serializable: `part 'current_file_name.g.dart';`
for freezed: `part 'current_file_name.freezed.dart';`

2. Make sure you saved changes for the current file before running `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding envied_generator in your pubsec.yaml file under dev_dependenciens.
https://pub.dev/packages/envied_generator/install

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to [explains why this package solves the problem, how it solves the problem and show how to use the package](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/14516046)

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating injectables. Make sure you also have `injectable_generator` in your `dev_dependencies`.

The frustrating thing about this issue is that no error occurs. Since you have  `build_runner`, running `dart run build_runner build` will execute with no errors but 0 outputs. In my case, adding `injectable_generator` finally got my injectables injected!